# how to get data according to month only?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have writen a query but it gets data according to `date month year` but I want to get data group by month only how i do this? Here is my query:

```
select a.entered,a.credit,
(select a.account_id from listing,article r where a.account_id=r.account_id group by 
a.account_id) as article,(select a.account_id from listing,event e where 
a.account_id=e.account_id group by a.account_id) as event,a.renewal_date from listing a 
where a.profit_instructor_id='0' group by  DATE_FORMAT(a.entered,'%m-%d-%Y')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EXTRACT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) or [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month):

```
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM a.entered)
GROUP BY MONTH(a.entered)
```

With you full query and EXTRACT:

```
SELECT a.entered,
       a.credit,

  (SELECT a.account_id
   FROM listing,
        article r
   WHERE a.account_id=r.account_id
   GROUP BY a.account_id) AS article,

  (SELECT a.account_id
   FROM listing,
        event e
   WHERE a.account_id=e.account_id
   GROUP BY a.account_id) AS event,
       a.renewal_date
FROM listing a
WHERE a.profit_instructor_id='0'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH
                 FROM a.entered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**MONTH()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function in group by it will group the months in all years you should group months with year also

```
SELECT 
  a.entered,
  a.credit,
  (SELECT 
    a.account_id 
  FROM
    listing,
    article r 
  WHERE a.account_id = r.account_id 
  GROUP BY a.account_id) AS article,
  (SELECT 
    a.account_id 
  FROM
    listing,
    event e 
  WHERE a.account_id = e.account_id 
  GROUP BY a.account_id) AS event,
  a.renewal_date 
FROM
  listing a 
WHERE a.profit_instructor_id = '0' 
GROUP BY MONTH(DATE_FORMAT(a.entered, '%m-%d-%Y')),
YEAR(DATE_FORMAT(a.entered, '%m-%d-%Y'))
```